# How to hide window title and menu bar in GNOME Shell?

Tags: unity, gnome, globalmenu, usability

Is it easily possible in GNOME 3's gnome-shell to achieve similar appearance of windows' title and menu bars as with Unity's Globalmenu?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289940/remove-title-bar-of-all-maximized-gnome-3-8-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer you directly - no its not "easy" for gnome-shell to have unity's global menu.

However, there is an alpha quality gnome-shell global unity patch available (patch below).

As to redisplaying the minimize-maximize and close decoration back-into gnome-shell - just use *gconf-editor* and change the key shown - note the position of the close - minimize - maximize buttons

[image]

### Compile Gnome-Shell global menu

```
sudo apt-get install git-core valac-0.12 libvala-0.12-dev libgtk-3-dev gobject-introspection libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev autotools-dev automake autoconf intltool libtool

cd
mkdir -p globalmenu
cd globalmenu
wget http://gnome2-globalmenu.googlecode.com/files/gnome-globalmenu-0.9.alpha5.tar.bz2
tar -xvf gnome-globalmenu-0.9.alpha5.tar.bz2

git clone git://github.com/gnome-globalmenu/gnome-globalmenu.git

cd gnome-globalmenu
git checkout gnome-3
cp ../gnome-globalmenu-0.9.alpha5/src/{module.c,header.h,header-gtk2.h} ./src

autoreconf --force --install --verbose
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make GTK2_MODULES_DIR=/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules GTK3_MODULES_DIR=/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/modules GLIB_COMPILE_SCHEMAS=/bin/true install
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas


sudo rm /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/GlobalMenu@globalmenu.org/{metadata.json,extension.js,stylesheet.css}
cd
wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/GlobalMenu-globalmenu.org.tar.gz
tar -xvf GlobalMenu-globalmenu.org.tar.gz
sudo cp GlobalMenu@globalmenu.org/{metadata.json,extension.js,stylesheet.css} /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/GlobalMenu@globalmenu.org/
sudo ln -sfv /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libglobalmenu-gtk2.so /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libglobalmenu-gtk.so
```

open GNOME Tweak Tool (install it in Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`) and enable the *Global Menu extension*

Now open *Dash* and search for *Startup Applications*

Add an entry `gnome-globalmenu-manager`

Complete the installation:

```
sudo cp ~/globalmenu/gnome-globalmenu/globalmenu.sh /etc/profile.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/globalmenu.sh
```

*not tested by myself - [original source](http://frijal.com/global-menu-ubuntu-gnome3/) and [updated instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/get-global-menu-in-gnome-shell.html)*

Comment: thanks! this seems also interesting: http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/ "Moving to GNOME 3"

Comment: instructions were updated as per http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/gnome-shell-global-menu-instructions.html

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at this post: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/get-global-menu-in-gnome-shell.html. It's about the same extension, but it provides instructions for different distros and Shell versions.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the window title use maximus:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Thats a new implementation (Note: is in beta): https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu