# When will globalmenu start to work with gnome-shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, globalmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide window title and menu bar in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62845/how-to-hide-window-title-and-menu-bar-in-gnome-shell)

When will globalmenu start to work with gnome-shell in Oneiric? Is there already a PPA or an alternate version of gnome-globalmenu that works with gnome-shell?

Answer (score 2):

See this post on how to build and install gnome-globalmenu extension: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/get-global-menu-in-gnome-shell.html.