# Keep the titlebar of Nautilus in Gnome Shell when maximized

Tags: 13.04, gnome, nautilus

(Gnome Shell, 13.04, Upgraded, Gnome 3.8 )

Except for Nautilus all applications have a title bar when maximized.

I want the title bar with close button, even when nautilus is maximized.

This is exactly the opposite of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289940/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing this extension [ignore_request_hide_titlebar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/515/ignore_request_hide_titlebar/) worked.