# Removing the Firefox top panel

Tags: gnome, firefox, 15.10

I would like to remove this top panel in Firefox (I'm using Firefox Developer Edition):
[image]

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10.

How do I remove the top panel hilighted in the picture above?

Comment: It's not a "panel", it's the Window title. On Ubuntu these are integrated in the top panel. On Gnome there was an extension to obtain the same, but I am not sure whether it still works...

Comment: Fonud it! [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/408700/29595) it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove title-bar of all maximized Gnome 3.8 windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289940/remove-title-bar-of-all-maximized-gnome-3-8-windows)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing on this page in 2020, please follow below steps on firefox:

1. go to Menu -> Customize…
2. you’ll see the “Title Bar” checkbox in the left bottom of customize tab, Un-check it to hide the title bar

ref: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/hide-firefox-title-bar-ubuntu-18-0416-04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Manikanta Please add actual code or steps and keep the site link as a reference as sites can go down or the site link might change

Answer (score 0):

Make full screen (F11) then press ctrl-L or ctrl-K. 
Works at least for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't exist, you could try this approach (the preference that the checkbox controls):

(1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful or accepting the risk.

(2) In the search box above the list, type or paste title and pause while the list is filtered

(3) If the browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar preference is currently false, double-click it to flip the value to true

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1237317