# How to use 17.10 with Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, 17.10

Is there any hope to bring back Unity on Ubuntu 17.10?

---

Personally, I (still) don't like Gnome. The main reason I like Unity is for the top bar integration (and the `Alt` suggestions).

I just couldn't find any *good* extensions for Gnome to do that.

I upgraded from `16.10` to `17.04` and then `17.10` (which came with Gnome). Everything went fine, but I just want Unity back...

How to do that?

---

I already tried:

```
ionicabizau@notebook:~$ sudo apt install unity
[sudo] password for ionicabizau: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unity is already the newest version (7.5.0+17.10.20171010-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

Comment: @pomsky I already tried that... maybe I didn't notice the enviroment select on login. Double-checking.

Comment: Hi...
I asked a similar question here [https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/screen-space-wasted-space]
I tried some of the suggestions and, to a point they worked however, in the end, they're a compromise. Unity is excellent for being efficient with screen space.

In the end, I did fresh 16.04LTS install back to Unity and, for the foreseeable future, that's where I'll stay.

Comment: However it isn't really recommended to use Unity in a long term. After all LTS support will finish Unity will be never maintained.

Comment: @SiGe I really hope somebody will take care of an environment similar to Unity... I'm so happy that I can use Unity again.

Comment: @Piloti Thanks for linking! I had exactly the same problem! I'm using a big display, but I hate that bar which doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple

```
sudo apt install unity
```

will Install Unity.

When signing in you then can switch to Unity.
[image]

Source: https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/

Be careful using this option, it is known to lock up the login screen.

Comment: *When signing in you then can switch to Unity.* – Indeed, there is a small gear icon near the login button. The second option in my case is *Unity*. Maybe you can post a screenshot with the login screen. :D Thanks!

Comment: In my case there is no gear icon, although Unity has been installed. How to proceed?

Comment: I've got the same behavior as @KristjanAdojaan