# How to hide title bar in Firefox 57 Quantum?

Tags: firefox

I used to use an extension to hide/show the title bar in Firefox, but since Firefox 57 was released most of the extensions were disabled.

In Chrome I just uncheck the option "Use system title bar and borders" and it's done.

Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: You can merge the title bar of maximised application windows with the Activities bar at the top following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966767/480481).

Comment: Thanks but I am using Kubuntu, altough KDE Plasma has an option to remove the title bar the maximize, minimize and cloase button disapear that makes it annoying.

Answer (score 93):

**Update - May 2018**

Firefox 60 has now been released to all users with support for Client Side Decorations. Go to *Menu > Customise* and uncheck *Title Bar* in the bottom left corner. This works in all distributions to my knowledge, although apparently it looks a little strange still in KDE.

You can check your browser version by going to *Menu > Help* and selecting *About Firefox*. If you are not yet on Firefox 60, you should be able to update through your distribution package manager or by [downloading it directly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/) from Mozilla.

The information below here is probably irrelevant unless you are on an older version of Quantum such as 57, 58, or 59.

---

#### Enable Client Side Decoration

If you are willing to switch to [Firefox 59](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/59.0a1/releasenotes/) (currently available on the Nightly channel), it supports a very rough prototype of CSD, or [Client Side Decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650646/what-is-client-side-decoration), which allows the browser to render its tab list where the title bar would normally be. This reduces the amount of window chrome at the top and probably gives the effect that you are looking for.

[image: CSD on FF57/Fedora]

On newer builds of Firefox Nightly, CSD can be enabled by going to *Menu > Customise* and unchecking *Title Bar* in the bottom left corner.

On older builds of Firefox Nightly, this option may not be present, and as such you may need to use the following method.

- Navigate Firefox to `about:config`
- Search for the property `widget.allow-client-side-decoration` and set it to `true`
- Reboot Firefox

Right now, this feature comes with the caveat that it may not work correctly on all systems. It certainly works on Fedora, and while is not working right now on my Ubuntu 17.10 PC there have been recent [articles](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/firefox-nightly-adds-csd-option) showing it working fine. If not, new Nightly versions are pushed out (unsurprisingly) every night so you can expect a fix very soon.

Comment: Thanks...but that means that is not possible to get in Firefox 57,  right?

Comment: I don't believe so, unless you are running Fedora (unlikely on this forum) or are willing to patch your installation with upstream changes. Nonetheless, it's something worth keeping in mind (and worth posting for anyone coming across this answer in the future), as these changes will be available in Firefox within months.

Comment: It odds how Chrome has make it done from a while and Firefox is still trying to do it.

Comment: It is odd how Ubuntu Quantum has no title bar on Unity (integrated with top bar), but on Gnome You can't hide it...

Comment: The `widget.allow-client-side-decoration` property doesn't appear to be present anymore, but there's a GUI element to do the same thing: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/firefox-nightly-adds-csd-option

Comment: This works on Firefox 58! (in fedora)

Comment: Funny enough, it works on Fedora with Firefox 58 but not on Arch on the same version. There, it doesn't have the titlebar checkbox, regardless of client-side-decoration.

Comment: Working on fedora 27 and  firefox 59, thanks pal.

Answer (score 22):

Just click the top-right menu (the hamburger(☰) menu) > `Customize`, you’ll be at the Customize Firefox page, on the bottom-left most, unchecked the `Title Bar`.

That’s it :)

[image: See here]

Comment: Best answer. No about:config stuff. Just three clicks and you're done!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, however, by the time I asked this question that feature had not been implemented yet in Linux environment.

Comment: Features are upgrading, answer are downgrading, answers are upgrading!

Comment: Best answer +1. To those concered, the maximum/minimum/close buttons will merge into the tabs bar automatically,  don't worry about losing them!

Comment: I don't have that anymore in Firefox 114 in kubuntu, and with older Ff ESR that option does nothing. The same with the about:config setting!

Answer (score 13):

In Firefox 61 `about:config` there is an option `browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar`. One can just set it to true.

Comment: This does the same thing as the [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143465/145907) answer

Comment: not for me (I'm on Ubuntu Mate 20.04).  Only this one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Gnome Shell you could also use [No Title Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/) extension.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve you problem!
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-title-bar/
Be sure to install Python script (details in addons page after installation). 
also install wmctrl package.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Title bar is boring specially on small screens.

1. First add this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-title-bar/
2. go to Firefox > tools > add-ons and click on more link and at the very bottom click on go to install page and download the .deb file and install.
3. `sudo apt install wmctrl`
   Reboot.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Those ones for which above mentioned methods didn't worked, Here is a **trick.**

**Right click on the title bar -> resize**  
-> resize the window to full screen and use it like this and never maximize the window. trust me it looks the same as maximized.

[image: same as maximized]

Comment: Is this gnome-specific?