# How do I get rid of the window tile of Firefox while retaining functionality?

Tags: gnome, firefox, gtk, window-manager, gtk3

Firefox uses space that I find redundant. I would prefer to have less space wasted by Firefox while keeping the window buttons.

This has wasted space:

[image: Big ol' waste of space that looks HOR-RI-BLE!]

This does not. How can I get it to look like the picture below instead?

[image: Not a big ol' waste o' space that looks horrible.]

Comment: Try to press **F11** ;)

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/ and for best effect https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/

Comment: Look at this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979968/how-to-hide-title-bar-in-firefox-57-quantum

Comment: Thank you so much, abu_bua. <3  You will forever hold a special spot in my heart. You have saved me much trouble. I love you.