# Firefox title bar missing

Tags: firefox

The title bar in Firefox is gone. I need it back.

Reasons: I need to easily enable/disable "Always on top". I need to be able to easily click drag FF by grabbing the title bar, not small space between tabs.

How can I be fixing the Firefox to have normal title bar like other apps have in the Ubuntu? Like how Firefox used to be when it was good browser?

What I have tried:

1. Googling a solution
2. searching FF preferences
3. right click on tab bar and random locations where the title bar used to be

System infos:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.10
Browser: Firefox 87.0 Beta 6
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here: Customize -> Title bar Checkbox (at lower left).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide title bar in Firefox 57 Quantum?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979968/how-to-hide-title-bar-in-firefox-57-quantum), see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143465/631600).

Comment: Thank you @pLumo, you are a living legend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click in the top part of Firefox e.g. in the tabs bar and select "Customize..." :
[image: Firefox Customize menu]

In the new window, check the "Title bar" box at the bottom left :
[image: Firefox Title bar checkbox]

That being said, even if you don't have the tile bar, you can probably keep Firefox always on top from the icon of your desktop task bar (here LXQt) :
[image: Desktop task bar]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the screenshots too FloT., you rock.  I hope that FF developers and usability folks improve on this as (a) the Title Bar checkbox is in blind spot on big monitors and (b) cannot find "title bar" anyway in preferences currently.