# Wasted Screen Space on Gnome / Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, lts

A year or so ago, I asked this question [Wasted screen space due to multiple horizontal bars at the top when an application is open in GNOME desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/wasted-screen-space-due-to-multiple-horizontal-bars-at-the-top-when-an-applicati?noredirect=1#comment1753632_966685)

In the end I decided to stick with 16.04 LTS. I am now being pinged / reminded that there is a new LTS version. I've had a poke around the Ubuntu pages / site and there are no *desktop* images that show how the screen space is managed.

So, in short, have the screen space issues been resolved in 18.xx LTS or is it still a case of add-ons, plug-ins and work arounds ? If it is the former, I may take the plunge and upgrade, if it is the latter, then I will stick with 16.04 LTS.

Thanks. P.

Comment: See https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/07/26/first-point-release-of-18-04-lts-available-today for fresh screenshots of Ubuntu with GNOME Shell. And http://ubuntu-mate.org/ for comparison with MATE :) Other option is to keep using Unity on 18.04 (install `ubuntu-unity-desktop` into it).