# How to remove the upper bar of applications

Tags: gnome, gui, window, titlebar, window-decoration

How do I remove the top bar of applications (title-bar), The one bar that usually displays minimize, maximize and close? See attached screenshot:

[image: top bar image]

Comment: From *all* windows or just *maximised* windows? It is relatively much easier for maximised windows: https://askubuntu.com/q/289940/480481

Comment: All windows, but only the window bar. Not the ubuntu one with battery

Comment: For browsers like Firefox and Chromium, they have a setting to turn the title bar off (i.e. merge it with the tab bar).

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome/Chromium go to *Settings* -> *Appearance* and turn off the '**Use system title bar and borders**' option:
[image: screenshot chrome]

For Firefox go to ☰ -> *Customize* and turn off the '**Title bar**' option in lower left corner:
[image: screenshot firefox]

Also for all applications you can use GNOME extension called [Pixel saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/). It removes title bar only from maximized windows but you will have access to maximize/minimize buttons in GNOME panel.