# Hide application menu from Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome

Is it possible to hide application's menu like in unity.
Firefox already hide its menu, and allow accessing it by clicking ALT button.

I'm using GNOME Shell 3.14.4.

Comment: Have a loook : http://askubuntu.com/questions/62845/how-to-hide-window-title-and-menu-bar-in-gnome-shell?lq=1

Comment: Did you check if it works for you?

Comment: @Hastur, it works only for terminal, I want it for all apps.

Comment: @Nasreddine, there could be some setting in  of the theme that you can use.  What have you found  till now? If it is not a feature of any theme, you can always switch to Unity if you prefer it. Or if you want you can always see in the code of gnome and firefox source code...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Terminal application you can simply

- Select View and deselect `Show Menubar`.

to restore it later you can right click on the Terminal and choose *select Show Menubar* .

If you want to associate this action with a keyboard shortcuts (I see difficult to associate it  only to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but for sure you can pick another combination of keys) you can set it up following [[2](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en)]

> - Open the Activities overview and start typing Keyboard.
> - Click on Keyboard to open the panel.
> - Select the Shortcuts tab.
> - Select a category in the left pane, and the row for the desired action on the right. The current shortcut definition will change to New accelerator…
> - Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to clear.

**Reference**

- The article about the [Menubar visibility](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-menubar.html.en) on the site help.gnome.org
- The article about how to [*"Set keyboard shortcuts"*](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) always on the gnome help site.